# Can one method in Symfony Controller take care of Rest and Web Request

Tags: rest, symfony, controller

I am developing web application using Symfony2.
Methods in Controller will be called from Web Application but at the same time I need to expose rest api for same functionality. For example Login and get data for a user.

Can one method be configured/written to server the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to determine the format of your response (HTML, JSON) from the controller(s), based on a parameter from the request. Have a look at the official Routing documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#book-routing-format-param

Now when it comes to REST applications, [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) makes things very easy for you. It allows you to configure *format agnostic controllers* in bunch. This is well documented in their "The View Layer" section.